# What is this vector equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

I was going through some documents and I came across this vector equation (the vector is composed of a real part and imaginary part):

if:

$ v = a + j*b $

then:

$w = \sqrt(|a|) * \sqrt(\frac{1 + \sqrt(1 + z^2)}{2})$

where:

$z = \frac{b}{a}$

I have not seen this equation before. Could someone explain this to me? What equation is this? I thought that this would be a unit vector but it is an odd way of writing it. The equation that I am wondering about is w. I am not sure what w is or what equation it is. I thought that w would be a unit vector but again, I am not sure.

Comment: Where does $w$ come from? It just suddenly appears out of nowhere.

Comment: I apologize, The question was not very clear. I edited the post to make it more clear but w is the equation that is in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is an expression for the real part of the square root of $v$. In polar coordinates, we have
$$v=a+jb=r\exp(j\theta)=r \cos(\theta)+j r\sin(\theta)$$
$$\sqrt{v}=\sqrt{r}\exp(j\theta/2)= \sqrt{r}\cos(\theta/2)+j \sqrt{r}\sin(\theta/2)$$

Inserting the polar expression for $v$ into your equation
$$w=\frac{\sqrt{\left| \cos (\theta)\right| } \sqrt{r (\left| \sec (\theta)\right| +1)}}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Assuming that $\cos (\theta)\geq 0$
$$w=\frac{\sqrt{r}\sqrt{  ( 1 +\cos (\theta))}}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{r}\cos(\theta/2)=\Re(\sqrt{v})$$

Comment: Yes, I believe that you are correct. However, I do not quite see how we go from what you have to waht I have. I think that there are a few trig identities that I am forgetting